# Apache, PHP, MYSQL on Windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, windows-7, webserver

What is the best (and easiest) way to set these up on Windows 7? I have tried Xampp and WAMP but all I get after installing them is a blank local host. So I create a php info file using the following code:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Put it in the httpdocs folder, call it using http://localhost/info.php and I get a 404 file not found error. Even though I followed the typical install settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with either xampp or wamp. The problem was with the proxy that is installed where I was using the internet. It has blocked access to the localhost. Bypassing the proxy for localhost in Internet options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Proxy Server does not fix this for wireless so to access the webserver I have to disconnect from the network to what I need to do and then reconnect.
The web server worked fine when I was on other non proxy networks.

Comment: If on windows, you can also make an entry in your hosts file so it looks like 127.0.0.1 localhost  That should do the trick.  Or change localhost to whatever you want. and access it by http://whatever

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance running Skype in the background? Skype claims port 80 and port 443 as a firewall workaround. You can disable this in the advanced options -> connection.

This happens to me almost all the time I set up a new PC...